# Serializing base class that has no jaxb annotations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a base class that I edit, so I cannot add jaxb annotations to it.
In the derived class I want to serialize some of the base class's attributes.
How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

If you cannot modify the classes to annotate them, then you may be interested in external mapping document extension in **EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**.

**oxm.xml**

Below is the external mapping document equivalent of the metadata I have specified in one of the examples on my blog ([JSON Binding with EclipseLink MOXy - Twitter Example](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html)).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="blog.json.twitter">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SearchResults" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="completedIn" name="completed_in"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Result" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="createdAt" name="created_at">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="blog.json.twitter.DateAdapter"/>
                </xml-element>
                <xml-element java-attribute="fromUser" name="from_user"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Demo**

The code to bootstrap the JAXBContext with the external mapping document would look like:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "blog/json/twitter/oxm.xml");
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {SearchResults.class}, properties);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In this MyClass is not annotated with JAXB annotations. MyClass is a typical java bean class.

```
       try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
        MyClass cl = new MyClass();
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(new JAXBElement<MyClass>(new QName("","MyClass"), MyClass.class, cl), System.out);

    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```